# Making a frameset remember it's cols (width) the next time the page is loaded

Tags: javascript, persistence, frameset

I am trying to force persistence on to a frameset - I want to make it work so that the user is able to set his desired width (cols) for the frame and make sure the value is saved and loaded the other time the user accesses the page.

I am using this simple example page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadFrameWidth()
{
    document.getElementById('masterFrameset').cols = '150,*';
}

function storeFrameWidth()
{
 alert(document.getElementById('masterFrameset').cols);
}
</script>
</head>
<frameset id="masterFrameset" border="3" frameborder="1"
onLoad="loadFrameWidth()" onUnload="storeFrameWidth()">
  <frame id="controls" name="controlsFrame" src="about:blank" />
  <frame id="content" name="contentFrame" src="about:blank" />
 </frameset>
</html>
```

The problem that happens is that when I exit the page (the moment when it is "supposed" to store the width in a cookie) the "cols" value is not updated even if I have manually changed the width of the columns (via mouse).

Comment: tested on firefox 3.6.6, IE8 and IE8(compat). I get nice popups with 150,* and after manually editing with 645,67% (in FF, because IE doesn't show the borders) What IS wrong?

Comment: I tested with Google Chrome only ;) Turns out it was working all the time.. Sorry for misleading, I should've tested with more than one browser. Btw, is there any way to force borders to be shown on IE 8?

Comment: I don't see the part where you are updating a cookie when the frame size is changed or where on page load it checks for the cookie value and updates the frame based on that value, if exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*** *A WORKING SOLUTION* *****

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function loadFrameWidth(cookieName)
{
    if (document.cookie.length>0)
 {
     c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName + "=");
  if (c_start != -1)
  {
   c_start = c_start + cookieName.length + 1;
   c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start);
   if (c_end == -1) { c_end=document.cookie.length; }
   document.getElementById('masterFrameset').cols = unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
  }
  else { setStandardWidth(); }
 }
 else { setStandardWidth(); }
}

function setStandardWidth()
{
 document.getElementById('masterFrameset').cols = '150,*';
}

function storeFrameWidth(cookieName)
{
 var currentCols = document.getElementById('masterFrameset').cols;
 var exdate = new Date();
 exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + 7);
 document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(currentCols) + 
 ";expires=" + exdate.toUTCString();
}
-->
</script>
</head>
<frameset id="masterFrameset" border="1" frameborder="1"
onLoad="loadFrameWidth('frameSetWidth')" onUnload="storeFrameWidth('frameSetWidth')">
  <frame id="controls" name="controlsFrame" src="toc.html" />
  <frame id="content" name="contentFrame" src="content.html" />
 </frameset>
</html>
```